# Facebook Authentication - new member and existing memeber?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-authentication

I have just implemented Facebook Authentication on my website using Facebook JavaScript.

If user logged on facebook from my website for the first time and then it need to insert data into `users` table (mysql) - maybe a field called `fb_userid` and email?

I have read the Documentation on JavaScript SDK that I can get Facebook User ID but how do I pass that into PHP so I can insert into `users` table?

Facebook Javascript look like this:

```
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'xxxxxxxx', // App ID
                status     : true, // check login status
                cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
                xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });

        (function(d){
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
        }(document));
```

On the Login Page:

```
  <fb:login-button scope="email" autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button>
```

Is is possible to use PHP SDK to get the Facebook User ID?

Is it necessary to load Facebook JavaScript file before using PHP SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code gets the user data and serializes it, and throws to the database, i know its not perfect but have a look. I'm going to edit this when i get some free time, then i recommend encoding the users data as JSON, not as base64 serialized, because it will be easier to do query searches in the future.

```
<?php
    require 'facebook.php'; // USE FACEBOOK PHP SDK

    // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'APPID',
      'secret' => 'APPSECRET',
    ));
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Get User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    /* We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
       If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
       Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
       token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook. */

    if ($user) {
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $dt = $facebook->api('/me');
        $lk = $facebook->api('/me/likes');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Handler for Login Status
    if ($user) {
      $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    } else {
      $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "email,user_birthday,user_likes,user_work_history,user_location,user_education_history"));
    }
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ?>
    <?php if (!$user): header ('Location:'.$loginUrl.''); //CHECKS IF USER IS LOGGED IN
    else: 
    $con = mysql_connect("DATABASE IP","USERNAME","PASS");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    else{
    $id = base64_encode(serialize($dt['id']));
    $work = base64_encode(serialize($dt['work']));  
    $location = base64_encode(serialize($dt['location']));  
    $education = base64_encode(serialize($dt['education']));    
    $f_n = $dt['first_name'];
    $l_n = $dt['last_name'];
    $link = $dt['link'];
    $u_n = $dt['username'];
    $bd = $dt['birthday'];
    $gdr = $dt['gender'];
    $em = $dt['email'];
    $sportsS = base64_encode(serialize($dt['sports']));
    $languagedt = $dt['languages'];
    foreach($languagedt as $item){
        $language[] = $item;
    }
    $languageS = base64_encode(serialize($language));

    $lk_dt = $lk['data'];
    foreach($lk_dt as $value)
      {
      if ($value['category'] == "Musician/band" || $value['category'] == "Song" ){
        $fav_music[] = $value;
      } 

      if($value['category'] == "Tv show"){
        $fav_tvshow[] = $value;
      }

      if($value['category'] == "Book"){
        $fav_book[] = $value;   
      }

      if($value['category'] == "Movie"){
        $fav_movie[] = $value;  
      }

      if($value['category'] == "Games/toys"){
        $fav_games[] = $value;  
      }

      if($value['category'] == "Interest"){
        $interest[] = $value;   

      }

      if($value['category'] == "Professional sports team"){
        $sport_team[] = $value; 

      }

      // next is likes
      if ($value['category'] != "Movie" && $value['category'] != "Musician/band" && $value['category'] != "Book" && $value['category'] != "Games/toys" && $value['category'] != "Tv show" && $value['category'] != "Professional sports team" && $value['category'] != "Interest" && $value['category'] != "Tv show" && $value['category'] != "Professional sports team" && $value['category'] != "Song") {
        $likes[] = $value;
      } 
    }
    $fav_musicS = base64_encode(serialize($fav_music));
    $fav_movieS = base64_encode(serialize($fav_movie));
    $fav_bookS = base64_encode(serialize($fav_book));
    $fav_tvshowS = base64_encode(serialize($fav_tvshow));
    $sport_teamS = base64_encode(serialize($sport_team));
    $fav_gamesS = base64_encode(serialize($fav_games));
    $interestS = base64_encode(serialize($interest));
    $likesS = base64_encode(serialize($likes));

    mysql_select_db("database", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, firstdone FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $f_dn = $row['firstdone'];
    $ctrl = $row['id'];
    if (!$ctrl){

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, language, fav_sports, education, location, work, first_name, last_name, link, username, birthday, gender, email, fav_music, fav_movie, fav_books, fav_tv, fav_sport, fav_games, interest, likes)
    VALUES ('$id', '$languageS', '$sportsS', '$education', '$location', '$work', '$f_n', '$l_n', '$link', '$u_n', '$bd', '$gdr', '$em', '$fav_musicS', '$fav_movieS', '$fav_bookS', '$fav_tvshowS', '$sport_teamS', '$fav_gamesS', '$interestS', '$likesS')");      

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.php') {
        header('Location: /theprofilepage');}
    }
    else{
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET language='$languageS', fav_sports='$sportsS', first_name='$f_n', last_name='$l_n', link='$link', username='$u_n', birthday='$bd', gender='$gdr', email='$em', fav_music='$fav_musicS', fav_movie='$fav_movieS', fav_books='$fav_bookS', fav_tv='$fav_tvshowS', fav_sport='$sport_teamS', fav_games='$fav_gamesS', interest='$interestS', likes='$likesS', work='$work', location='$location', education='$education' WHERE id='$id'");

    }
    mysql_close($con);

    }endif
    ?>
```

U can get the values you want with JavaScript then pass them as values on the header, by the "location" function, then the php would get those info with $_GET, by i do recommend using the PHP SDK to do the auth stuff. But you choose. And you can also use them together.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to me that your best bet would be to use Javascript (jQuery as well in my example) to call a PHP page in background that adds the users to the database.

Page head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function (data)
{
      file = 'adddata.php?data=' + data;
      $.get(file, function(content)
      {
          if (content == 'OK')
          {
              alert('Data added to the database!');
          }
          else
          {
              alert('Error adding data to the database!');
          }
      });
}
</script>
```

Example of *adddata.php*:

```
<?php
$dblink = mysqli_connect(mysql_data_here);
$query = 'INSERT INTO users VALUES (' . $_GET['data'] . ');';
$ok = $mysqli_query($query);
if ($ok == true)
{
    echo 'OK';
}
else
{
    echo 'Failed';
}
?>
```

You'd need to escape the incoming data in the PHP script of course and change the SQL query a bit, but this is the general idea.