# Authentication in Facebook application

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am working on a Facebook application and I can successfully get the user's info in JSON after authorizing. However, when I refresh the page, I'm redirected to Facebook for OAuth when I thought that the authorization had already taken place. I had understood that I only needed an access token, subsequently.

```
if (fbData != null)
    {
        if (fbData.user_id == null)
        {
            var redirURL = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + fbAuthURL.Replace("[APPID]", appId).Replace("[REDIRECT]", (Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + canvasPage));
            Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> " + Environment.NewLine +
                    "top.location.href=\"" + redirURL + "\";" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "</script>");
            Response.Write("Redirect URL for Authorization : " + redirURL);
        }
        else
        {
            if (isReady == true)
            {
                MyWebRequest userRequest = new MyWebRequest("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + accessToken);
                string userInfo = userRequest.GetResponse();
                //Response.Write(userInfo);
                FBAuth fuser = new FBAuth();
                UserInfo oUser = fuser.GetUserInfo(userInfo);
}}}
```

How can I handle it?

Comment: Are we supposed to be able to read that? You would get answers a lot faster with properly formatted code. A big blob of code is not enticing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019734/facebook-authentication-new-member-and-existing-memeber/8028572#8028572

Comment: Since you're using C# to check the Oauth authentication, why not just do a response redirect in C# to authenticate and get the token back?